# How to patch or mock subsequent API calls in python unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have following function

```
def test_dir_creation():
    if not os.path.exists(root_dir_path):
        raise Exception("Root dir don't exits")

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir_path):
        raise Exception("Log dir don't exits")

    if not os.path.exists(subscription_handle_dir_path):
        raise Exception("subscription_handle_dir_path dir don't exits")
```

I want to test three conditions for that my test case is as follows -

```
@mock.patch("os.path.exists", return_value=False)
def test_args_parser_when_root_dir_dont_exists(*mocks):
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as excinfo:
        args_parser()
    expected_message = "Root dir don't exits"
    assert expected_message in str(excinfo)
```

This test case works but I want to test other two conditions as well, how to do that?

How I can patch something like os.path.exists(log_dir_path) == False?

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking the call *for the entire function* in your example. If you want to have the mock change behavior, I would recommend using a context manager.

```py
import os.path


def do_test():
    with mock.patch('os.path.exists', return_value='hello'):
        assert os.path.exists() == 'hello'
    with mock.patch('os.path.exists', return_value=-5):
        assert os.path.exists() == -5
```